# Script time improvement

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to improve time efficiency of part of my script but I don't have any more idea. I ran following script in either Matlab and Python but Matlab implementation is four times quicker than Python 's one. Any idea how to improve ?

**Python**:

```
import time
import numpy as np

def ComputeGradient(X, y, theta, alpha):
    m = len(y)
    factor = alpha / m
    h = np.dot(X, theta)
    theta = [theta[i] - factor * sum((h-y) * X[:,i]) for i in [0,1]]
    #Also tried this but with worse performances
    #diff = np.tile((h-y)[:, np.newaxis],2)
    #theta = theta - factor * sum(diff * X)
    return theta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt("data_LinReg.txt", delimiter=',')    
    theta = [0, 0]
    alpha = 0.01
    X = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    X = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(y)), X))
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(0, 1500, 1):
        theta = ComputeGradient(X, y, theta, alpha)
    stop_time = time.time()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (stop_time - start_time))
```

--> 0.048s

**Matlab**:

```
data = load('data_LinReg.txt');
X = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
m = length(y);
X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)]; % Add a column of ones to x
theta = zeros(2, 1);
iterations = 1500;
alpha = 0.01;
tic
for i = 1:1500
   theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha);
end
toc

function theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha)
   m = length(y); % number of training examples
   h = X * theta;
   t1 = theta(1) - alpha * sum(X(:,1).*(h-y)) / m;
   t2 = theta(2) - alpha * sum(X(:,2).*(h-y)) / m;
   theta = [t1; t2];
end
```

--> 0.01s

**[EDIT]** : solution avenue

One possible avenue is to use numpy vectorization instead of python root functions. In the proposed code, replacing `sum` by `np.sum` improves the time efficiency so that it is closer to Matlab (0.019s instead of 0.048s)

Furthermore, I tested separately the functions on vectors : np.dot, np.sum, * (product) and all these functions seems to be faster (really faster in some case) than the equivalent Matlab. I wonder then why it is still slower in Python....

Comment: Do you want to improve your MATLAB implementation too?

Comment: Why not, I tried with this : ``temp=repmat(h-y,1,size(X,2));theta = theta - alpha * (sum(X.*temp))' / m;`` but it is slower due to repmat. But the goal is really to improve Python script

Comment: Could you add the file data_LinReg.txt?

Comment: data_LinReg.txt could be anything you want, something like ``x=0:0.01:10;y=3*x+2+x(end:-1:1).*randn(1,size(x,2));save('data_LinReg.txt','x','y','-ascii')`` for example

Comment: good question. On my computer with 20 trials the factor was more than 6. Maybe try [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This solution presents an optimized MATLAB implementation that does -

- Funtion-inlining of the `gradient-descent` implementation.
- Pre-computation of certain values that are repeatedly used inside the loop.

Code -

```
data = load('data_LinReg.txt');

iterations = 1500;
alpha = 0.01;
m = size(data,1);

M = alpha/m; %// scaling factor

%// Pre-compute certain values that are repeatedly used inside the loop
sum_a = M*sum(data(:,1));
sum_p = M*sum(data(:,2));
sum_ap = M*sum(data(:,1).*data(:,2));
sum_sqa = M*sum(data(:,1).^2);
one_minus_alpha = 1 - alpha;
one_minus_sum_sqa = 1 - sum_sqa;

%// Start processing
t1n0 = 0;
t2n0 = 0;
for i = 1:iterations
    temp = t1n0*one_minus_alpha - t2n0*sum_a + sum_p;
    t2n0 = t2n0*one_minus_sum_sqa - t1n0*sum_a + sum_ap;
    t1n0 = temp;
end
theta = [t1n0;t2n0];
```

Quick tests show that this presents an appreciable speedup over the MATLAB code posted in the question.

Now, I am not too familiar with python, but I would assume that this MATLAB code could be easily ported to python.

Comment: How much is (approximately) "an appreciable speedup"? Thanks.

Comment: @PabloEM With number of rows as `10000` for `data`, I am getting over `1000x` speedup on MATLAB.

Comment: Looks interesting, but works as is because you exactly know that it is a 2D regression. If I add a regression factor, we need to modify the code which is not efficient. But the idea of preprocessing is good

Comment: @GuillaumeA How would you add the `regression factor`? Edit the question with it? I am not clear on that.

Comment: Well, imagine you'd like to perform a regression on (1, x, x^2) and not only on (1, x)... you'll need theta of dimension 3 so that you have more pre-computed variables.

Comment: @GuillaumeA So, something like `X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1) data(:,1).^2];` and rest stays the same?

Comment: yes. The code I proposed is less efficient than yours but you can pass it a data of any size

Comment: @GuillaumeA Well yeah the code presented here is a customized version of what you had presented originally in the question. Extending this to a general case would involve a lot more work.

Comment: @GuillaumeA Just curious, what exactly is your case for `X`. Is it `X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)];` or `X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1) data(:,1).^2];` or something else or you can't say?

Comment: @Divakar, for the example, it was [ones(m,1), data(:,1)] but I tried to design something more generic without assuming any shape of the input vector(s). Could be of size (m,2), (m,3) or (m,n). Your implementation was really good in the case of a line regression, but not applicable for a parabola or any higher degree polynomial regression. Anyway, good example of code optimization.

Comment: @GuillaumeA Ah okay, well for me code optimizations are all about abusing the limitations of the problem. Also, I was thinking about porting the presented solution to Python, but since you are looking for a generic case solution, I don't think I would find the motivation there. Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much of a difference it will make, but you can simplify your function with something like:

```
s = alpha / size(X,1);
gradientDescent = @(theta)( theta - s * X' * (X*theta - y) );
```

Since you need theta_{i} in order to find theta_{i+1}, I don't see any way to avoid the loop.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is more on the Python side than in the Matlab side as Matlab is already 4-5 times quicker than Python...

Comment: Then why would you post the matlab code and use the matlab tag?

Comment: Because it is always interesting to improve Matlab code, even if I would like to focus on Python code. Process efficiency does not depend on language much. Every Matlab improvement could possibly apply to Python.